# Without AC how to construct a surjection between powerset of a cardinal to another cardinal?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

With Axiom of Choice, we could have some consequences between $2^{\aleph_{\alpha}}$ and $\aleph_{\alpha}$ or some other cardinals without having to construct a map. If without AC, the cardinality of $2^{\aleph_{\alpha}}$ is not defined. Can we construct a surjection from $\mathcal{P} (\aleph_{\alpha})$ to $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that your claim

> without AC, the cardinality of $2^{\aleph_\alpha}$ is not defined

is false. The cardinality of a set is definable, with or without choice (although without choice, the way we define "cardinality" is more complicated). What is true is that without choice, we can't prove that the cardinality of $2^\kappa$ is an $\aleph$-number.

(Incidentally, even with choice we can't prove *which* $\aleph$-number something like $2^{\aleph_0}$ is - e.g. it is consistent with ZFC that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, but it's *also* consistent with ZFC that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_{\omega^2+17}$.)

---

Now on to your actual question:

**Yes**, ZF alone proves that there is a surjection from $\mathcal{P}(\aleph_\alpha)$ to $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$.

The key is the following observation: that $\aleph_\alpha$ is infinite well-orderable by definition, and $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the cardinality of the set of isomorphism types of well-orderings of subsets of $\aleph_\alpha$. To prove this, first show that $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the cardinality of the set of ordinals of cardinality $\le\aleph_\alpha$ (think about why $\aleph_1$ is the cardinality of the set of countable ordinals), and then try to show that every ordinal of cardinality $\le\kappa$ can be represented by a well-ordering of a subset of $\kappa$.

*Given the claim above*, we now build the desired surjection $o$. Since $\aleph_\alpha$ is infinite and well-orderable, there is a bijection $b$ from $\mathcal{P}(\aleph_\alpha)$ to $\mathcal{P}(\aleph_\alpha\times\aleph_\alpha)$ (exercise). For $A\in\aleph_\alpha$, let $o(A)$ be defined as follows:

- If $b(A)$ is a well-ordering of a subset of $\aleph_\alpha$, then $o(A)$ is the ordertype of $b(A)$.
- Otherwise, $o(A)$ is the ordertype of the usual ordering on $\aleph_\alpha$.

The map $o$ is (exercise) a surjection from $\mathcal{P}(\aleph_\alpha)$ to the set of well-orderings of subsets of $\aleph_\alpha$; so we're done.

---

Interestingly, ZF does *not* prove that there is an *injection* from $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ to $\mathcal{P}(\aleph_\alpha)$! E.g. the [axiom of determinacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy) implies that there is no injection from $\aleph_1$ to $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Isn't any subset of $\aleph_\alpha $ well-ordered by inclusion and its type $\leq$ $\aleph_\alpha $? Then how could the set of these types of cardinality $\aleph_{\alpha+1} $?

Comment: @Nicky Any subset of $\aleph_\alpha$ is well-ordered and has ordertype $\le\aleph_\alpha$, but different subsets can have the same ordertype (e.g. think about the natural numbers vs. the even natural numbers). The set of *subsets* of $\aleph_\alpha$ can be (even in ZFC) much bigger than the set of *ordertypes of* subsets of $\aleph_\alpha$.

Comment: "$\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is the cardinality of the set of isomorphism types of well-orderings of subsets of $\aleph_{\alpha}$." I asked because I'm not very clear about this statement. Isn't the "isomorphism type" the order type and is a unique one $\leq \aleph_\alpha$?

Comment: @Nicky: We're considering _arbitrary_ well-orderings of subsets of $\aleph_\alpha$, not just ones that come from restricting the usual order.

Comment: @Nicky Ah, I see your question now. I didn't say "well-ordered subsets of $\aleph_\alpha$," I said "well-**orderings** of subsets of $\aleph_\alpha$." For example, if we take $\aleph_0$, then the relation "$2<4<6<8<...<0$" is a well-order of a subset of $\aleph_0$ (namely, the evens) of ordertype $\omega+1$ - it doesn't correspond to the ordertype of any subset of $\aleph_0$ *with the usual ordering*.

Comment: Thanks, I see now.  And could you give me some hint about how to correspond every ordinal of cardinality $\leq \kappa$ to a well-ordering of a subset of $\kappa$ ?

Comment: @Nicky "Cardinality $\le\kappa$" means "there is an injection to $\kappa$" - do you see how to use this to turn an ordinal of cardinality $\le\kappa$ into an **ordertype of** a well-ordering of a subset of $\kappa$? (It won't correspond to a *single* well-ordering - that would require choice - but it will correspond to a *set* of well-orderings, all of which have the same ordertype.)

Comment: The cardinality of the set of $\leq \aleph_\alpha$-ordinals is $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ and each $\leq \aleph_\alpha$-ordinal corresponds to a set of well-orderings, then how to say the set of well-orderings is of $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$?

Comment: @Nicky "The cardinality of the set of $\le\aleph_\alpha$-ordinals is $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$" You have to be careful here - not the ordinals $\le\aleph_\alpha$, but the ordinals **whose cardinality is** $\le\aleph_\alpha$; and in fact $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is precisely the set of these ordinals. The set of (ordertypes of) well-orderings of subsets of $\aleph_\alpha$ *of length $\le\aleph_\alpha$* has size $\aleph_\alpha$ of course, but the set of (ordertypes of) well-orderings of subsets of $\aleph_\alpha$ has size $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$.

Comment: Start small: do you understand that the set of *countable* ordinals has cardinality (in fact, is) $\aleph_1$?

Comment: I could understand that. But I don't know why the set of (ordertypes of) well-orderings of subsets of $\aleph_\alpha$ has size $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$. If each ordinal of cardinality $\leq \aleph_\alpha$ corresponds to a set of well-orderings but not a single one.

Comment: @Nicky I don't know what you're still confused by. (i) $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ is exactly the set of ordinals of cardinality $\aleph_\alpha$. So we want to find a way to assign to each subset of $\aleph_\alpha$ an ordinal $<\aleph_{\alpha+1}$, which is surjective. (ii) Let $b$ be a bijection between $\mathcal{P}(\aleph_\alpha)$ and $\mathcal{P}(\aleph_\alpha\times\aleph_\alpha)$; for $S\subseteq\aleph_\alpha$, let $f(S)$ be the ordinal of the same ordertype as $b(S)$ if $b(S)$ is well-ordered, and let $f(S)=0$ if $b(S)$ is not well-ordered. (continued)

Comment: (iii) This defines a map from $\mathcal{P}(\aleph_\alpha)$ to the set of ordinals with cardinality $\le\aleph_\alpha$, since $f(S)$ always has cardinality $\le\aleph_\alpha$. So we just need to show that it's surjective. (iv) Let $\theta$ be some ordinal with cardinality $\le\aleph_\alpha$. Since $\theta$ has cardinality $\le\aleph_\alpha$, there is an injection $i$ from $\theta$ to $\aleph_\alpha$. Let $C$ be the image of this injection, and $D$ be the induced ordering of $C$: $D=\{(x, y)\in C^2: i^{-1}(x)<i^{-1}(y)\}$. Then $f(b^{-1}(D))=\theta$.

Comment: Do each of these steps make sense? If not, which one(s) is problematic? If so, do you understand how this gives a surjection from $\mathcal{P}(\aleph_\alpha)$ to $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69303/discussion-between-nicky-and-noah-schweber).